# Access to <ng-content> using ContentChild

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access `ng-content` elements in my component  ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶t̶t̶a̶c̶h̶ ̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶, ̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶k̶e̶e̶p̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶o̶n̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶c̶l̶e̶a̶n̶.

```
import {
  Component,
  ContentChild,
  ElementRef,
  AfterContentInit,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom',
  template: `
    <span class="wrapper">
      <ng-content #projectedContent></ng-content>
      <ng-content select="[confirmButton]"></ng-content>
    </span>
  `,
})
export class CustomComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild('[confirmButton]', { static: true }) confirmButton!: ElementRef;
  @ContentChild("projectedContent", { read: ElementRef }) projectedContent: ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.confirmButton);
    console.log(this.projectedContent);
  }
}
```

```
<!-- somewhere in parent component -->
<custom>
  <button>Hello</button>
  <button confirmButton>Confirm</button>
</custom>
```

I've tried accessing in `AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit` lifecycle hooks, I've tried ContentChildren. Every time it comes as undefined, I could only access via `ViewChild` the `.wrapper` div.

Answer (score 0):

> The events like click, input, etc bubble up can be captured in
> the parent as shown below

**Parent.component.html**

```
<custom (click)="btnClicked($event)">
  submit
</custom>
```

**Parent.component.ts**

```
btnClicked($event) {
   console.log($event)
   alert('button clicked')
 }
```

**custom.component**

```
import {
  Component,
  ContentChild,
  ElementRef,
  AfterContentInit,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom',
  template: `
    <span class="wrapper">
     <button>
         <ng-content #projectedContent></ng-content>
     </button>
    </span>
  `,
})
export class CustomComponent {

}
```

[source](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/ng-content-content-projection-in-angular/#Events)

Comment: It's a nice idea, unfortunately I still need to access the <ng-content> projected element. Also <button> needs to be in the parent, as it is a dynamic element.

Comment: The `submit` will pass inside `ng-content `, so you have access from parent. 
Also the `<button>` can be handled in parent but "lives" in child.